# Meaning of the word "anchor"

Tags: meaning

On the page on this [link](http://applemusic.tumblr.com/beats1) it says "Beats 1 Anchors".

> Beats 1 Anchors. Always On.

What does the word Anchor mean in that context? What is the duty of the "Anchors"?

Comment: Can you add to your question what different dictionaries said the word "Anchor" means, and what you don't understand about that?

Comment: Generally anchors are the solid grounding, the basic foundation, the steadying forces.  Your most favorite songs would be your musical anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context - a radio station - I believe that **Anchor** in this case is the OED's sense 4:

> **Anchor**
>
> 4. Chiefly N. Amer an anchorman or anchorwoman

And **anchorman** is:

> **Anchorman**
>
> 1. a person who presents and coordinates a live television or radio programme involving other contributors

This is advertising the Beats 1 radio station's three primary presenters, the three individuals presented directly below the title.

Comment: I think you’re right, what’s odd is that radio usually has DJ’s while news shows have anchors.